# C++ - Dynamic Shadow Casting

Tags: c++, algorithm, shadow

I am doing a game project for school and I've come across an issue with lighting. I have read a lot of tutorials and the topic and none have seemed to work for me. The only working algorithm I could produce was through bruteforcing lines with raycasts (which obviously led to
framerate issues, etc). What is the best way to project shadows onto a 2D plane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using something like OpenGL, there are many tutorials out there on the subject. If you are writing your own renderer, you will have to do a bit more work, though the same principles apply.

There are many ways to get shadows, but a lot depends on your needs and compute power. The two methods that I would say are the most popular/common are

1. Raytraced Shadows
2. Shadow Maps

**Raytraced shadows** are, in my opinion, way easier to understand and implement. Basically when you are shading a pixel, you cast a ray toward the light source where the maximum ray length is the distance to the light. If the ray does not hit anything, then the point you are shading is considered not to be in shadow. If the ray hit distance is smaller than the distance to the light, it is in shadow. In plain English you can think of this as, if my eye were to be located at this position in the world, do I have a direct line of sight to the light?

This approach will give you perfectly hard edged shadows. This is because the light source is considered infinitely small. It can get a little more complicated when you want soft shadows or a spotlight cone-angle falloff.

**Shadow maps** are by far the more commonly used in real-time/game applications, though as the number of cores increases in newer machines, I believe shadow maps will become less and less relevant.

Here's a tutorial about Shadow Mapping in OpenGL, but the concept is the same as you'd find for any other rendering system.
http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/

In a nutshell, a shadow map is just a render of your 3D scene from a light's point of view, but rather than storing color for your objects in the scene, you store depth values. Then later when you are rendering from the camera's point of view you use the shadow map as a look-up for depth values. The point you are shading from the camera's point of view need to be transformed into the space of the same view/projection matrix that was used to generate the shadow map (or depth image), so you know where the pixel being shaded would be if rendered from the light's point of view.

Shadow maps tend to take up more memory and are usually faster than raytracing.
raytracing takes up hardly any memory, can be threaded very easily, but the speed cost of casting rays can get very expensive if the scene has a lot of geometry.

There are many more ways to add shadows, but without more specifics about what you want, it will be difficult to give direction. If for example you just want a dark area under your character in a game, you could fake shadows using a sprite with a circle gradient on it. Sprite shadows are insanely fast, but will not look right unless your floor is perfectly flat. If you want accurate shadows on a flat surface, you could also use projection shadows, which you are basically using ray-casting to project your geometry from the lights position onto the floor, and render it black. But again, it really depends on your needs. You might want to update your questions with more specifics about your project.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write that out for me! I am using SFML for rendering but I will still look into the tutorials you've showed me. I should have put this into the question but I am looking for mostly projecting points over a light map (kind of like [this](https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSr5zX8jQpNZ6V6-tW43mkIdEyGVIiJ9DgJ3tC-FjKATHbbwGPrQg))

Comment: I just started using SFML myself to handle the window, events, sound, and network stuff. I am surprised there aren't any tutorials about shadow mapping for it. At least, I didn't find any with a quick web search. Though, SFML uses OpenGL under the hood, you should be able to insert your own OpenGL commands between the SFML commands. The tricky part with shadow maps is you need an offscreen framebuffer to store the depth image, and there are several ways to handle that. If your shadows will not be moving, I'd look into light-maps (baking lighting into textures)

Comment: Yeah, I have Google'd relentlessly trying to find anything on it. I am making a roguelike dungeon crawler so my shadows will most likely need to be dynamic.

Comment: Ultimately you will probably want cube-map shadows so you can have that torch light effect. It's basically the same thing, but you render shadow maps for each side of the cube that you need shadows projected from. That's the only way I am aware of doing point-light shadows. You could probably do all this in Unity with minimal effort, but not sure if that would violate the rules of the class you are taking. I'm also guessing that shadows are not required for your class since they haven't taught you how to do it ;) Might want to focus on gameplay/design and worry about lighting/effects later.